# Sublime text 3 Package-Control won't install in windows 10

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

Installing package-control using console. It shows an error :

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '0_package_control_loader.sublime-package'`

Need solution to avoid this error. Currently I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Are you running "console" as an administrator? Do you have write permissions to the installation/data directories of sublime text?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Sublime Text as Administrator, and then install the Package-Control plugin.

Note : I also had to upgrade to the latest build of Sublime. After installation, the plugin had problem loading.

Comment: What if I don't have Admin privileges?